# Failed to clean directory in ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-cli

Failed to clean directory --EPERM: operation not permitted

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvvN4.jpg]

Comment: This issue  was  faced while running  'ionic cordova run android'           
       Error: Failed to clean directory C:\Users\Admin\Sample_app_debug\www\build - EPERM: operation not permitted.   Any answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem working for android.

This was the solution that worked for me:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform android
```